# Scope Lambda wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone please have a look what I'm doing wrong? 
It's Rails 3:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :postingtemplate

    scope :active, (lambda do |ad| 
        Item.exists?(:postingtemplate => ad.postingtemplate_id)
    end)

end
```

It's a scope inside Ad model, and is supposed to return all ads, for which Item exists where `item.postingtemplate == ad.postingtemplate_id`

**UPDATE**

Broke it into two scopes and it worked :)

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postingtemplate
  scope :active, where(:postingtemplate_id => Postingtemplate.active)
end

class Postingtemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
  scope :active, where(:id => Item.all.collect{|x| x.postingtemplate}.uniq)
end
```

if anyone knows a better way - feel free to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a [`join`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

```
scope :active, lambda { |ad| joins(:postingtemplate => :items).where(:postingtemplate => {:postingtemplate_id => ad.postingtemplate_id}) }
```

Maybe this will work too:

```
scope :active, lambda { |ad| joins(:postingtemplate => :items).where(:postingtemplate => ad.postingtemplate) }
```

Comment: strangely they both give the same error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. Is it possible that i should use something else instead of "where" part?

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling this scope. Are you passing any parameters for the call. Please paste in the line, where you are calling the scope

Comment: Oh, I get it :) was calling it like this: `Ad.active`. That's ok - found another way